# Shifting org headlines in evil insert state

Tags: org-mode, evil

With the org-evil package, normal state `>` on a headline executes
`org-evil-demote`, but on normal text it executes `evil-shift-right`.  Two
questions:  (1) How does this work?  (2) It would be nice (and probably more
appropriate?) if a similar behaviour were bestowed on insert state `C-t`, and
correspondingly on `C-d` (`H-t` and `H-d` in my configuration), such that
`evil-shift-right-line` and `...-left-...` would demote and promote headlines
when point is on headlines.  How might one achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want you have to either remap the keys in your `init` file or modify evil-org. You probably will want to do the former. And I think `org-metaleft` and `org-metaright` will do what you want (i.e. either promote or demote header or list item). You just need to set the keys for insert mode. So something like

```
(evil-define-key 'insert 'org-mode-map
  "C-t" 'org-metaleft
  "C-d" 'org-metaright)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This looks like it would shift headlines instead of de- and promoting them.

Comment: thanks - I think I misunderstood the OPs question. Have modified accordingly.